# Timestamp: Pressing F5 notepad gives time 1st then date. How do I do date 1st then time?

Tags: mouse, macros, shortcuts, hotkeys, notepad

When I open notepad, I can press F5 to give me the time in the format I desire and then the date in the format I desire, where the formats I desire are based on windows settings.

The only thing missing is to have date and time interchanged.

How do I do this please?

1. Well one way is to press F5, press space, press F5 again and then copy/cut/delete as appropriate, but...
2. I'm hoping to have date and time with only 1 (or 2 or 3) button(s).
3. I have a razer mouse, and I can create/import macros, but this seems like a wheel reinvention and kind of a hassle.
4. I discovered autohotkeys and posted an answer below, but I'm hoping for something simpler.

Please suggest something simpler, such as adjusting notepad settings to give me date 1st then time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the tags informed me of the existence of AutoHotKeys, so here's an answer:

1. Using notepad, create a file named for example date&time.ahk (save as a '.ahk' file)
2. Here's an example

Put this in the file

```
(insert desired hotkey)::
FormatTime, DateTimeString,, (insert desired timestamp format)
Send, %DateTimeString%
return
```

For example

```
^XButton2::
FormatTime, DateTimeString,, ddd yyyyMMMdd h:mmtt
Send, %DateTimeString%
return
```

The hotkey is `ctrl`(the `^`)+`mouse4`(the `XButton2`), and the output looks like:

> Thu 2020Jun11 7:35am